# Как вывести дерево двоичного поиска (Binary Search Tree) в виде String

Tags: java, бинарное-дерево

Здраствуйте. Есть рабочий код который когда вызываю метод `print()` возвращает `Binary Search Tree` в виде диаграммы с символами и цифрами как надо мне. Проблема в том что мне надо возвратить не просто символы и цифры а чтоб они все были в одном `String` который будет возвращен. И непонятно как это сделать.

```
@Override
    public String prettyPrint() {
        
        return null; //Тут я должен возвратить дерево в виде String
    }



public void print() {
        print("", "", "", "");
    }

    public void print(String prefix, String left, String mid, String right) {
        String indent = " ".repeat(String.valueOf(data).length());
        if (leftChild != null) {
            leftChild.print(prefix + left + indent, " ", "┌", "│");
        }
        System.out.println(prefix + mid + data
                + " ┐┘┤".charAt((leftChild  != null ? 2 : 0)
                + (rightChild != null ? 1 : 0)));
        if (rightChild != null) {
            rightChild.print(prefix + right + indent, "│", "└", " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: дерево полное или произвольное? Значения узлов уникальные или могут повторяться? В чем проблема писать строчками `parent left right`, например `1 2 3` будет означать, что удел `1` имеет 2 потомка -  левый `2` и правый `3` - и так строчку для каждого узла, у которого хотя бы 1 потомок есть?

Comment: для полного дерева можно вообще просто массив из 2*N элементов вывести в строку.

Comment: Вопрос заключается в том как это дерево что получается на выходе конвертировать в String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) имеет тип [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html), так что мы можем написать более общий метод, передавая в него `PrintStream`:

```
public void print() {
    print(System.out, "", "", "", "");
}

public void print(PrintStream stream, String prefix, String left, String mid, String right) {
    String indent = " ".repeat(String.valueOf(data).length());
    if (leftChild != null) {
        leftChild.print(stream, prefix + left + indent, " ", "┌", "│");
    }
    stream.println(prefix + mid + data
                + " ┐┘┤".charAt((leftChild  != null ? 2 : 0)
                + (rightChild != null ? 1 : 0)));
    if (rightChild != null) {
        rightChild.print(stream, prefix + right + indent, "│", "└", " ");
    }
}
```

После этого можно подставить [свой поток и преобразовать его в строку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760654/java-printstream-to-string):

```
public String prettyPrint() {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final String utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
    try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos, true, utf8)) {
        print(ps, "", "", "", "");
    }
    return baos.toString(utf8);
}
```

Ну это вариант с наименьшими изменениями.
**Второй вариант** это использовать [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Аналогичным образом передавать его в метод и вызывать `append` добавляя переносы строки:

```
@Override
public String prettyPrint() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    prettyPrint(builder, "", "", "", "");
    return builder.toString();
}

private void prettyPrint(StringBuilder result, String prefix, String left, String mid, String right) {
    String indent = " ".repeat(String.valueOf(data).length());
    if (leftChild != null) {
        leftChild.prettyPrint(result, prefix + left + indent, " ", "┌", "│");
    }
    result.append(prefix + mid + data
                + " ┐┘┤".charAt((leftChild  != null ? 2 : 0)
                + (rightChild != null ? 1 : 0)));
    result.append("\n");
    if (rightChild != null) {
        rightChild.prettyPrint(result, prefix + right + indent, "│", "└", " ");
    }
}
```

После этого можно `print` переписать так чтобы использовался `prettyPrint`.

P.S. Код не компилировал, если возникнут ошибки придется немного поправить.